# More Efficient Runtime in Scheme - AVL's

Tags: runtime, scheme, avl-tree

So I basically have the function avl? that run's in O(n^2), this is so because everytime im recursing, I'm calling height which is O(n) function (where n is number of nodes in a tree).

```
(define (height t)
  (cond
    [(empty? t) 0]
    [else (+ 1 (max (height (BST-left t)) (height (BST-right t))))]))

(define (avl? t)
  (cond
    [(empty? t) #t]
    [else (and (avl? (BST-left t))
               (avl? (BST-right t))
               (>= 1 (abs (- (height (BST-left t))
                             (height (BST-right t))))))]))
```

My problem is that i want to make avl? run in O(n) time. I was given the hint: "You should try to limit calling your height function within a constant time no matter how large the BST you are applied to. In this way, you can get a O(n) running time over all." ... I'm not sure how to make my height run in constant time thou. Any suggestion to make my avl? run in O(n) rather than O(n^2)?

Comment: caching? what exactly is that ?

Comment: Storing information to avoid recomputing it.

Comment: I'm not allowed to created a structure tht will store the height, or use set! notation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not allowed to store the height in the tree, you can avoid recomputing it by having a worker function that tells you the height of a tree *and* if it's an AVL tree. Then each node is looked at exactly once, and you have an O(n) algorithm. Then call the worker from the wrapper that forgets the height part of the worker's result. You should of course short-cut, so if some subtree is determined to violate the balancing condition, don't bother checking any more subtrees, return `#f` and a bogus height.

Comment: I have the worker height that will tell me the height of a tree..? but how will i also make the worker tell me if it's an avl tree?

Comment: Make a new worker, returning a pair of `(isAVL, height)`. `(define (helper t) (cond [(empty? t) '(#t 0)] [...]))`.

Comment: hmm i have trouble with the else case, `[else '((and (first (height (BST-left t)))
                 (first (height (BST-right t)))
                 (>= 1 (abs (- (second (height (BST-left t)))
                               (second (height (BST-right t))))))) (+ 1 (max (second (height (BST-left t))) (second (height (BST-right t))))))]))`

Comment: Does scheme do common subexpression elimination? If not, you'd have to assign the result of the recursive calls to a variable. What trouble have you? Looks okay from here.

Comment: The output just procudes the expressions in a list without computing them .... `'((and (first (height (BST-left t))) (first (height (BST-right t))) (>= 1 (abs (- (second (height (BST-left t))) (second (height (BST-right t))))))) (+ 1 (max (second (height (BST-left t))) (second (height (BST-right t)))))) `

Comment: Errm, now is the time where actually knowing some Lisp dialect would be helpful. I suppose `first` and `second` are aliases for `car` and `cdr`, are they? And does `'(1 2)` produce a pair/list with these two elements? Otherwise you may need to use `cons`. By the way, I wouldn't call that function `height`, it does (well, is supposed to do) more than that.

Comment: yes car and cdr are aliasis for first and second ... and '(1 2) does produce a pair/list .. its just weird how the statements aren't being computed and then being placed into the list rather it just putting the statements in the list :(

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8690/discussion-between-daniel-fischer-and-beginnernato)

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be storing the height in every node, where the value represents the height of the subtree rooted in that node. Clearly, with this approach returning the height of a subtree would be an O(1) operation.

That implies that all the operations that modify the tree (insertion, deletion, etc.) must keep the height up to date whenever there's a structural change in the tree.

Comment: Yea the thing is i can't store the height in a structure... and can't use mutation either, all i got is the hint given by a prof, which im not shure how i will limit my height function within a constant time